# How to create a React Native package (View) which depends on other Native packages

Tags: javascript, react-native, cocoapods, node-modules

Long story short, I am currently creating an npm package for React Native that is dependent on other packages that are native and require linking, pod install, etc.
I am currently using peerDependencies to make it work but I would like to include everything in the package for people to enjoy an easy installation process instead of manually installing 3-6 dependencies themselves.

I am not sure where to start about that or if it's even possible, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: In your install instruction write a note about running commands like `cd ios && pod install` and easily add the native dependencies to your module

Comment: @Mohammad I explicitly wrote in the first post that I was looking for the opposite of what you are suggesting

Comment: I don't see your first post. By the way, to be more clear I meant, add the other packages as your **dependencies**, not your peer dependencies, and do not ask the user to add them manually.

Comment: Autolinking doesn't work for the said packages?

Comment: Nope, it does not, some libraries it depends on requires to make modifications in AppDelegate and such, I will provide more in-depth information asap

Answer (score 1):

I think the first think you should check is [this library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob). It's actually recommended by the official React Native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup).

You can create basic bootstrap for your npm package with this command (check the link above to RN docs for more information):

```
npx create-react-native-library react-native-awesome-module
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for a far as I read, or at least not enough in-depth or me to get the context of this answer

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna use a native package then you will need for

## IOS

you will need to add `s.dependency` in `react-native-pkgname.podspec` [REF](https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor/blob/0497f6891697398fe2e9785fb503443cff78f939/react-native-compressor.podspec#L19)

## Android

you will need to add `implementation` in `android/build.gradle` file [REF](https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor/blob/0497f6891697398fe2e9785fb503443cff78f939/android/build.gradle#L61)

To make new package, you can use this CLI
https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob

```
npx create-react-native-library react-native-awesome-module
```

Comment: The references helped me to fix my issue. In references, the developer has added Cocoapods/maven dependency. I had to use local files for dependency that I fixed with a little hit and trial. Lemme know if someone needs help with the same.